# If $f(x)$ is differentiable, then isn't $|f(x)|$ not differentiable where $f(x)=0$ and differentiable everywhere else?

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, absolute-value

Problem 2-13 (d) of Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* is:[image]

But isn't $|f(t)|$​ always differentiable everywhere that $f(t)$ is differentiable and not equal to $0$? So isn't it impossible to find a differentiable function $f(t)$ such that $|f(t)|$ is nowhere differentiable?

Comment: A function is called 'not differentiable in $\Omega$ (open)' already if there is one point in $\Omega$ in which it is not.

Comment: Also note that $|f|$ _could_ be differentiable where $f(x) = 0$, see for instance $f(x) = x^2$, where $|f|$ is very much differentiable, even though $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Right, thank you for both of those comments. That makes sense, and I think pretty much answers the questions, though I welcome any other comments or answers anyone might have.

Comment: But then the question becomes too easy:  The identity function $f(x)=x$ has the desired property, for example.

Comment: @Mark Fischler Yeah, for that reason the question seems somewhat strange and out-of-place, if that is the kind of answer Spivak intended

Answer (score 2):

*From the comments above.*

---

A function is called "not differentiable in $\Omega$", where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, if there is some point in $\Omega$ where it is not differentiable. So, the question is not asking for a $|f|$ to be differentiable nowhere; you just need it to be non-differentiable somewhere in the domain.

---

Additionally, do note that $|f|$ can sometimes be differentiable even at those $x$ for which $f(x) = 0$, such as when $f(x) = x^2$.